# Android fade in text character by character

Tags: android, textview, fade

I am trying to create a screen as follows:

```
               Some very long text, saying something
```

Now, what I want is for the splash screen to load with the image ONLY, then I want the text underneath it to fade in character by character:

Frame 1: S

Frame 2: So

Frame 3: Som
etc...

My layout looks like this (I am not showing the image yet):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/fader">    
    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

My Java looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);  

    View faderLayout = findViewById(R.id.fader);

    TextView[] faderTextViews = getFaderTextViews();  
    for(int i=0; i<faderTextViews.length; i++)
    {
        ((LinearLayout) faderLayout).addView(faderTextViews[i]);
        faderLayout.invalidate();

    }

}


private TextView[] getFaderTextViews()
{

     final Animation in = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        in.setDuration(3000);

        final Animation out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        out.setDuration(3000);
     char[] veryLongString = "This is a very long string".toCharArray();
     TextView[] faderTextViews = new TextView[veryLongString.length];
     for(int i = 0; i<faderTextViews.length; i++)
     {
         TextView temp = new TextView(this);
         temp.setText(veryLongString, i, 1);
         temp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         temp.startAnimation(in);
         faderTextViews[i] = temp;

     }
     return faderTextViews;

}
```

What ends up happening is that the entire string is faded in at once.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) addselection.getBackground();

@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    frameAnimation.start();
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

add drawable with this type of xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_selection0001" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_selection0002" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_selection0003" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_selection0004" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_selection0005" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_selection0006" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Set different images for your sequence animation.set this drawable as your background in imageview.

There is a relatively simple example on the official docs website here: 
[Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I think I did not explain myself very well. I am trying to make the text fade in one by one, not images. You can assume I have no images at all, just a textview where I will try to set some text programatically, and I want the characters to fade in one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This is good:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Animator anim = fadeStringIntoViewGroup((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.fader), "A very, very long string.", 3000);
    //here you can add a another listener to anim if you want (a listener could manipulate the views by set ids).
    anim.start();
}

private Animator fadeStringIntoViewGroup(ViewGroup faderTextContainer, final String vls, int duration){
    Context context = faderTextContainer.getContext();
    final FrameLayout textViewHolder = new FrameLayout(context);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    final TextView helper = new TextView(context);
    textViewHolder.addView(helper);
    textViewHolder.addView(textView);

    SpannableString helperString = new SpannableString(vls);
    helperString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), 1, vls.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    helper.setAlpha(0);
    helper.setText(helperString);
    setupCreatedViews(faderTextContainer, textViewHolder, textView, helper);

    final int length = vls.length();
    final int stepDuration = duration/length;
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(helper, "alpha", 0, 1).setDuration(stepDuration);
    anim.setRepeatCount(length);
    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        int at = 1;
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            if (at < vls.length()) {
                SpannableString textViewString = new SpannableString(vls);
                textViewString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), at, length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                textView.setText(textViewString);
                helper.setAlpha(0);
                SpannableString helperString = new SpannableString(vls);
                helperString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), 0, at, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                helperString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), at + 1, length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                helper.setText(helperString);
                at++;
            }
        }
    });
    return anim;
}

private void setupCreatedViews(ViewGroup containerForAnimatedText, FrameLayout subcontainer, TextView textView, TextView textViewFadeinLetter){
    containerForAnimatedText.addView(subcontainer, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //here you can set colors, font sizes, ids, padding etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those (like me) who arrived here from Google, here's a nice library that can do exactly what the asker wanted :

https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView

Sadly for me, these animations only work for inline texts (multiple lines will be cropped). Still, I think it's pretty useful as well as simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed something like this, so made one of my own. Try out [Fade-In TextView](https://github.com/ChahatGupta/FadeInTextView-Android), a custom TextView library that prints texts letter by letter with a nice fade-in animation. Usage is also easy.

**In the XML layout**

```
    <believe.cht.fadeintextview.TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        app:letterDuration="250"/>
```

**And in the Java class**

```
  believe.cht.fadeintextview.TextView textView = (believe.cht.fadeintextview.TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

  textView.setLetterDuration(250); // sets letter duration programmatically
  textView.isAnimating(); // returns current animation state (boolean)
  textView.setText(); // sets the text with animation
```